# Error - JDBC Connection issue - unable to acquire

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection, weblogic, aix

11-08-2023 06:10:03.380 [ERROR] [biller-connect] com.billdesk.service.BillerConnectCRRMServiceImpl | traceId=PP012308110440256981807957132230440_fetch, bbpsTxnId=null, requestType=FETCH, billerId=BESCOM000KAR01 | message=Exception while sending response to BOU
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://xxxxx:7003/****/BillerConnectFetchResponse": Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
11-08-2023 06:10:03.394 [ERROR] [biller-connect] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper | Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
11-08-2023 06:10:03.398 [ERROR] [biller-connect] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper | Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
11-08-2023 06:10:03.398 [ERROR] [biller-connect] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper | Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
11-08-2023 06:10:03.398 [ERROR] [biller-connect] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper | Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
11-08-2023 06:10:03.398 [ERROR] [biller-connect] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper | Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
11-08-2023 06:10:03.398 [ERROR] [biller-connect] org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler | Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void com.billdesk.service.BillerConnectCRRMServiceImpl.saveWorkflowStatus(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.billdesk.common.models.LogTrace)
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object

We kill long running / inactive sessions.
It is working for some time but face same issue of unable to acquire jdbc connection ..

Answer (score 0):

The key part there is:  "Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object"

In simple terms, you have a connection pool of size "n", and (from the connection pool's perspective) all "n" are currently allocated to some sort of task, and you are person "n+1" to come along.

Thus you have to wait until a session in the pool becomes available to you to use, and you waited so long that we gave up.

The quick "solution" is a larger pool, but generally, this approach just defers the inevitable. You really need to tackle the root cause, namely, why are sessions not being released back to the pool